# Extensions and libraries for Django

Tags: python, django, plugins, libraries

Where can find all the extensions and libraries for Django in one place. http://planetdjango.org/ seemed have all the news but not all of the libraries.

Something like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ with ratings and comments by the community

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best place by far is http://djangopackages.com/. It has a very novel approach to organizing apps, it's a great resource. It has a grid system which makes it easy to compare apps with similar features. It's built on an [opensource django project](https://github.com/cartwheelweb/packaginator), and it seems they will be launching a pythonpackages.com soon as well.

Comment: Yeah it's excellent :) I'm looking forward to pythonpackages.com as well. I'm sure they'll both become invaluable.

Answer (score 1):

I like to look at [**`http://djangopackages.com/`**](http://djangopackages.com/)

I also like to look at [**`http://djangosnippets.org/`**](http://djangosnippets.org/) for some... snippets (custom models/managers/tags/filters) =)